# What kind of uniform is this?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

This is a picture of an uncle and his friend taken about 1925 or 1930. I don't know if he was in the US military or not, but this seems to be a US Infantry uniform. Can anyone identify the uniform?

I note the rifles seem to be authentic Springfield 1903, the cartridge belt is authentic, and the leggings look authentic. But no unit identifying badges, and I can't see what the hat badge might be. Perhaps this was a situation where people could dress up like a soldier to get a souvenir picture?

[image: Two men in uniform holding rifles]

Comment: With a little more info, like birth date and location you might be able to confirm military service through a [genealogy search](https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bgivenname%3Aalfred~%20%2Bsurname%3Acarlson~%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1905-1915~&collection_id=2028680).

Comment: I have birth date of 26 May 1905 and death date of 14 March 1976, but I don't know birth place - US for sure, but might be Wisconsin or Minnesota or North Dakota.  Can't find anything on Family Search or general googling.

Comment: Now that I look harder, does seem to be a USMC cover device. Thanks for that!

Comment: I didn't find military records, but [this record](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VPHR-LTD) at Family Search has him born in North Dakota.

Comment: That would be right. And Ancestry has a military record that seems to fit. I'll need to pursue that entry to find out service branch and dates. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, the answer is no, this is not a US Army uniform as the cover (what you call hat) device is the United States Marine Corps' [Eagle, Globe, and Anchor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle,_Globe,_and_Anchor).

Now to see if this is an authentic USMC uniform...

Comment: [USMC WWI uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BirthdayPageant_29Palms_081104-M-6603L-046.jpg)  Not implausible, but I'm not a devil-dog.

Comment: [Another, which looks similar to me](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwesharepics.info%2Fimageagkl-american-soldier-uniform.asp&bvm=bv.129391328,d.dmo&psig=AFQjCNF2MOAFCr4K7prSYwQYiaavsZJstA&ust=1470528231037583)